# run kde settings strating awesome wm

Tags: arch-linux, kde, awesome

I'm running an up to date Manjaro KDE and Awesome WM on side.

I did some mouse/touchpad configuration via KDE > System Settings.

Wich I'm able to activate in Awesome WM with this sequence :

- Mod4 + P
- select *Settings* > *KDE system settings* > *Input Devices* > *Touchpad*
- click to *[Apply]*

How to do the same at AwesomeWM's bootstrap in a script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally changed the way to solve my issue. Instead of trying to run some KDE touchpad settings in AwesomeWM. I used my own script using [xinput](https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man1/xinput.1.xhtml).

**1) create the script**

Using result of `xinput list` then `xinput list-props "DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD Touchpad"` I made the following script to fit my needs.

```
#!/bin/sh
# touchpad-conf
# set tap to click
xinput --set-prop "DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD Touchpad" 298 1
# set natural scrolling
xinput --set-prop "DLL0665:01 06CB:76AD Touchpad" 281 1
```

**2) make usage of `~/.xintrc`**

In my case (system running with [SDDM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SDDM))  I had to install first [xinit-session.aur](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/xinit-xsession/).

Then modify `~/.xintrc`

```
#!/bin/sh

#
# ~/.xinitrc
#
# Executed by startx (run your window manager from here)
#

if [ -d /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d ]; then
  for f in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/*; do
    [ -x "$f" ] && . "$f"
  done
  unset f
fi

~/bin/touchpad-conf &
exec awesome
```

**3) enjoy the new config**

Kill my current X session. Select *xinitrc* in *SDDM*. And that's it.